# Get ViewModel's coroutine scope with Hilt

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, coroutinescope

Suppose, I have ViewModel class with some UseCase in its constructor. This UseCase, on the other hand, has a CoroutineScope in its constructor. And I want to use the viewModelScope as an argument. Can I do it with Hilt?

```
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideUseCase(scope: CoroutineScope) = MyUseCase(scope)
}

...

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewMode(useCase: MyUseCase): ViewModel() {
...
}
```

As far as I understand, `ViewModelComponent` only has `SavedStateHandle` as a default binding, not even ViewModel itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your UseCase depends on the scope of the ViewModel that consequently depends on the UseCase, you have a dependency loop and you can't resolve it using Hilt.

You'd be better off passing down a provider for the UseCase, and initializing it inside the ViewModel, or better yet, not depend on the CoroutineScope and instead make your UseCase interface `suspend`

You can use KTX extensions for lifecycle-aware components, and use the `viewModelScope` extension. See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines).

Comment: Yeah, I know that there is a dependency loop, and I was going to use a Provider. But how can I use the viewModelScope in this exact configuration?

Comment: You can't, since its derived from the context of the ViewModel. You'd have to invert the dependence in this case

Comment: @Ov3r1oad can you share your solution? I had the same problem

Comment: @Andra I don't have it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the Assisted Injection feature of Hilt/Dagger. This method involves creating a factory for your `MyUseCase`, which allows you to pass the `CoroutineScope` as needed. Your factory setup might look like this:

```
@Singelton
@AssistedFactory
interface MyUseCaseFactory
{
    fun create(scope: CoroutineScope): MyUseCase
}
```

Then, update your `MyUseCase` to accept the `CoroutineScope` through assisted injection. This simply means adding it to your constructor, alongside any other dependencies you have. Here's how you might do it:

```
class MyUseCase @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted scope: CoroutineScope,
    // other dependencies..
) {
    // use case implementation...
}
```

Lastly, in your `MyViewModel`, you just need to inject this factory and use it to instantiate your `MyUseCase`, passing in the `viewModelScope`. The code in your ViewModel would look something like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel(factory: MyUseCaseFactory): ViewModel() {
   val useCase = factory.create(viewModelSope)
   // view model implementation...
}
```

And that's it! By using Assisted Injection, you have the flexibility to inject objects at runtime such as `viewModelSope`.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I've come to the exact same problem in my work. And I've found at least three solutions.
One of the main problems with `viewModelScope` is that it is only initialized after the VM constructor has finished. But it is available at the time of the `init{}` block  's execution.

My main solutions are:

1. Have a property in the useCase for a coroutine scope, then in the VM's `init{}` block assign `viewModelScope` to the `useCase.coroutineScope` property. Or have a method that would initialize usecase's scope to the viewModel one. Just make sure that the useCase does not interact with its scope before it is assigned.
2. Inject everything that the useCase needs in the viewModel's constructor, have a `private val useCase` property in the viewmodel. then construct the usecase inside the viewModel's `init{}` block, passing to useCase's constructor the injected objects plus the viewModelScope. I have ended up using this option.
3. Have a separate DI module (I am using Hilt, so am explaining in the Hilt's terms), apply `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class`) to the module, then create a `@Provides` method for a CoroutineScope there, apply the `@ViewModelScoped` annotation to the method. Then have that scope injected in the UseCase's constructor with `@Inject`. Provide the UseCase from a module which is also installed in a `ViewModelComponent` and scope the UseCase `@Provides` method with `@ViewModelScoped` as well ,then `@Inject` it into the ViewModel. This way you will essentially have a CoroutineScope equivalent to the viewModelScope. You might also want to add a qualifier to such scope to distinguish it from the ones for other viewmodels, if needed (use @Qualifier or @Named). This approach could be used in general to create an arbitrary amount of CoroutineScope's that can be scoped to any lifecycle, even to the application.

There are other options, like passing `viewModelScope` as an argument to the methods of UseCase, or having methods of UseCase be an extension of CoroutineScope (`fun CoroutineScope.yourMethod(){}`) or just marking all the methods in the UseCase as `suspend` and launching them from the viewModel.

Feel free to correct me if I am mistaken somewhere.